# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'MarkupListURI'. One of '{MarkupDeleteURI}' is expected

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, sax, saxparseexception

I have been attempting to resolve this final issue with validating the return xml from the api to the xsd, in almost all instances that are similar the solution is to add the following line: elementFormDefault="qualified" however this line is already included in both the originating xsd and the child xsd.

The submitted xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><SignedConfig>
  <Config>
    <RequestID>9cb5b8fe-62d8-4d52-ba32-58f1d1cc5909</RequestID>
    <ClientID>1234</ClientID>
    <ClientIP>172.1.1.0</ClientIP>
    <HelpURI>http://www.google.com/HELP_URI</HelpURI>
    <BravaServerURL>http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL</BravaServerURL>
    <UserName>Kenneth Test</UserName>
    <MaxCacheSize>1</MaxCacheSize>
    <NumberPreloadedPages>2</NumberPreloadedPages>
    <UseMultiPartPost>false</UseMultiPartPost>
    <ResolveDBTokensURI>http://www.google.com/RESOLVE_DBTOKENS_URI</ResolveDBTokensURI>
    <UI>
      <UiOverride>UI Variant</UiOverride>
      <CssOverride>CSS Theme</CssOverride>
      <SinglePageLayout>true</SinglePageLayout>
      <EnableRasterRenderer>true</EnableRasterRenderer>
      <Hide>
        <Widget>closeButton</Widget>
      </Hide>
    </UI>
    <Documents/>
    <Features>
      <Search>
        <MatchCase>true</MatchCase>
        <WholeWord>true</WholeWord>
        <RegEx>true</RegEx>
        <EnableTermHits>true</EnableTermHits>
        <DefaultTermHits>true</DefaultTermHits>
        <InitialSearch>Initial Search</InitialSearch>
      </Search>
      <Thumbnails>
        <InitialWidth>13</InitialWidth>
      </Thumbnails>
      <Markups>
        <SaveParameters>
          <SaveParams/>
        </SaveParameters>
        <ChangemarkConfigURI>http://www.google.com/CHANGEMARK_CONFIG_URI</ChangemarkConfigURI>
        <EnableMarkupOverwrite>true</EnableMarkupOverwrite>
        <AlwaysOverrideSave>true</AlwaysOverrideSave>
        <EnableAutosave>true</EnableAutosave>
        <AutosaveMinutes>7</AutosaveMinutes>
        <StampPreviewSize>8</StampPreviewSize>
        <ImagePreviewSize>0</ImagePreviewSize>
        <MarkupEditListURI>http://www.google.com/MARKUP_EDIT_LIST_URI</MarkupEditListURI>
        <MarkupReviewListURI>http://www.google.com/MARKUP_REVIEW_LIST_URI</MarkupReviewListURI>
        <MarkupSaveURI>http://www.google.com/MARKUP_SAVE_URI</MarkupSaveURI>
        <MarkupListURI>http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL/markups/9cb5b8fe-62d8-4d52-ba32-58f1d1cc5909?bravaserverurl=http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL</MarkupListURI>
        <MarkupDeleteURI>http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL/markups/delete/9cb5b8fe-62d8-4d52-ba32-58f1d1cc5909?clientid=1234&amp;bravaserverurl=http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL</MarkupDeleteURI>
      </Markups>
      <Print>
        <TimeoutMinutes>9</TimeoutMinutes>
      </Print>
      <Publish>
        <TIFFTimeoutMinutes>12</TIFFTimeoutMinutes>
        <PDFTimeoutMinutes>11</PDFTimeoutMinutes>
      </Publish>
      <ViewMode>
        <InitialZoom>Initial Zoom</InitialZoom>
        <MarkupEdit>Markup Edit</MarkupEdit>
        <RotateAll>14</RotateAll>
      </ViewMode>
      <TextSelect>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      </TextSelect>
      <Download>
        <DocumentURI>http://www.google.com/DOCUMENT_URI</DocumentURI>
      </Download>
      <ExportBanners>
        <PersistSettingsOnNewBanner>true</PersistSettingsOnNewBanner>
        <PresetsURL>http://www.google.com/PRESETS_URL</PresetsURL>
        <Watermark>
          <Text/>
          <Color>#ff0000</Color>
          <Editable>true</Editable>
          <Opacity>0.25</Opacity>
        </Watermark>
        <TopLeft>
          <Text/>
          <Color>#ff0000</Color>
          <Editable>true</Editable>
        </TopLeft>
        <TopCenter>
          <Text/>
          <Color>#ff0000</Color>
          <Editable>true</Editable>
        </TopCenter>
        <TopRight>
          <Text/>
          <Color>#ff0000</Color>
          <Editable>true</Editable>
        </TopRight>
        <BottomLeft>
          <Text/>
          <Color>#ff0000</Color>
          <Editable>true</Editable>
        </BottomLeft>
        <BottomCenter>
          <Text/>
          <Color>#ff0000</Color>
          <Editable>true</Editable>
        </BottomCenter>
        <BottomRight>
          <Text/>
          <Color>#ff0000</Color>
          <Editable>true</Editable>
        </BottomRight>
        <LeftTop>
          <Text/>
          <Color>#ff0000</Color>
          <Editable>true</Editable>
        </LeftTop>
        <LeftCenter>
          <Text/>
          <Color>#ff0000</Color>
          <Editable>true</Editable>
        </LeftCenter>
        <LeftBottom>
          <Text/>
          <Color>#ff0000</Color>
          <Editable>true</Editable>
        </LeftBottom>
        <RightTop>
          <Text/>
          <Color>#ff0000</Color>
          <Editable>true</Editable>
        </RightTop>
        <RightCenter>
          <Text/>
          <Color>#ff0000</Color>
          <Editable>true</Editable>
        </RightCenter>
        <RightBottom>
          <Text/>
          <Color>#ff0000</Color>
          <Editable>true</Editable>
        </RightBottom>
      </ExportBanners>
      <Redactions>
        <RedactionReasonsURI>http://www.google.com/REASONS_URI</RedactionReasonsURI>
        <RedactionPatternsURI>http://www.google.com/REDACTION_PATTERNS_URI</RedactionPatternsURI>
      </Redactions>
      <ESignature>
        <AcknowledgeText>Esig Ackknowledge Text</AcknowledgeText>
        <EnableRasterEdit>true</EnableRasterEdit>
        <Images>
          <Name>Image Name</Name>
          <Sign>Image Sign</Sign>
          <Seal>Image Seal</Seal>
          <Date>Image Date</Date>
          <Title>Image Title</Title>
          <Initial>Image Initial</Initial>
        </Images>
        <EnableRasterSaves>true</EnableRasterSaves>
        <ESigRasterSaveURL>http://www.google.com/RASTER_SAVE_URL</ESigRasterSaveURL>
        <EnableAutoTemplateCreation>true</EnableAutoTemplateCreation>
        <AutoTemplateInformation>
          <TotalSigners>6</TotalSigners>
          <CurrentSigner>5</CurrentSigner>
          <InitialsLocation>http://www.google.com/INITIALS_LOCATION</InitialsLocation>
        </AutoTemplateInformation>
      </ESignature>
    </Features>
    <CustomParameters/>
    <PrintFrameURI>http://www.google.com/FRAME_URI</PrintFrameURI>
    <SessionID>9cb5b8fe-62d8-4d52-ba32-58f1d1cc5909</SessionID>
    <PublishedDocumentURI>http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL/documents/9cb5b8fe-62d8-4d52-ba32-58f1d1cc5909/REVGQVVMVA?bravaserverurl=http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL</PublishedDocumentURI>
    <MobileDocumentURI>http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL/mobilepublishrequest/9cb5b8fe-62d8-4d52-ba32-58f1d1cc5909?bravaserverurl=http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL</MobileDocumentURI>
    <StampTemplateURI>http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL/stamptemplates?bravaserverurl=http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL</StampTemplateURI>
    <RasterURI>http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL/rasters/9cb5b8fe-62d8-4d52-ba32-58f1d1cc5909/1234?bravaserverurl=http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL</RasterURI>
    <SearchURI>http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL/search/9cb5b8fe-62d8-4d52-ba32-58f1d1cc5909?bravaserverurl=http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL</SearchURI>
    <SearchTextURI>http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL/search/searchtext/9cb5b8fe-62d8-4d52-ba32-58f1d1cc5909?sessionid=null&amp;clientid=1234&amp;bravaserverurl=http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL</SearchTextURI>
    <SearchIndicesURI>http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL/search/searchindices/9cb5b8fe-62d8-4d52-ba32-58f1d1cc5909?sessionid=null&amp;clientid=1234&amp;bravaserverurl=http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL</SearchIndicesURI>
    <MarkupRastersURI>Please remove as required</MarkupRastersURI>
    <HighlightURI>http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL/highlight/9cb5b8fe-62d8-4d52-ba32-58f1d1cc5909?bravaserverurl=http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL</HighlightURI>
    <PublishToFormatURI>http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL/publishtoformat/9cb5b8fe-62d8-4d52-ba32-58f1d1cc5909?bravaserverurl=http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL</PublishToFormatURI>
    <EventsURI>http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL/events</EventsURI>
    <Licenses>
      <License>markup_edit</License>
      <License>markup_review</License>
      <License>print</License>
      <License>branding</License>
      <License>pdf</License>
      <License>tiff</License>
      <License>redact</License>
    </Licenses>
  </Config>
  <Signature>grTCaJZBWOuj4x2GzCljvaqvMThayeA3gwTgbIfc2anQec6tUoBsPlEN6GSysxV4xmg8vn8QieWWFwE7CBXlVGsoPA3XFgAlV+s9CYKi1NIRziXwUTkSUbaJL8fJ2BWCPZXbi4A80Hz9CCtXY4mYZ82E2bCqMLAPx3xgm2L27AWvc3b7kznHTVidX6Mu0QAMGT7pxq666uBNh7K1ExRg56eerPQzhr9H1hdaZeOI21M0dOmTdwGMy8zlQ7HQlFhR696o0FLTtikVYH+Il38zsWuRXKXuCChvbZiH6DM8JL7xw3BHyL1fEyJwGvsd9/SgIKNIHualKYGxoGh4OodcMg==</Signature>
</SignedConfig>
```

The parent xsd is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="Config.xsd"/>
    <xsd:element name="SignedConfig" type="SignedConfigType" />
    <xsd:complexType name="SignedConfigType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Config" type="ConfigType" />
            <xsd:element name="Signature" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

And the child xsd is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="Config" type="ConfigType" />
  <xsd:complexType name="ConfigType">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="RequestID" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="ClientID" type="xsd:int" />
      <xsd:element name="ClientIP" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="HelpURI" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="BravaServerURL" type="xsd:anyURI" />
      <xsd:element name="UserName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="MaxCacheSize" type="xsd:int" />
      <xsd:element name="NumberPreloadedPages" type="xsd:int" />
      <xsd:element name="UseMultiPartPost" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:element name="ResolveDBTokensURI" type="xsd:anyURI" />
      <xsd:element name="UI" type="UIType" />      
      <xsd:element name="Licenses" type="LicensesType" />      
      <xsd:element name="Documents" type="DocumentsType" />
      <xsd:element name="Features" type="FeaturesType" />
      <xsd:element name="PublishedDocumentURI" type="xsd:anyURI" />
      <xsd:element name="MobileDocumentURI" type="xsd:anyURI" />
      <xsd:element name="StampTemplateURI" type="xsd:anyURI" />
      <xsd:element name="RasterURI" type="xsd:anyURI" />
      <xsd:element name="SearchURI" type="xsd:anyURI" />
      <xsd:element name="SearchTextURI" type="xsd:anyURI" />
      <xsd:element name="SearchIndicesURI" type="xsd:anyURI" />
      <xsd:element name="MarkupRastersURI" type="xsd:anyURI" />
      <xsd:element name="HighlightURI" type="xsd:anyURI" />
      <xsd:element name="PublishToFormatURI" type="xsd:anyURI" />
      <xsd:element name="EventsURI" type="xsd:anyURI" />
      <xsd:element name="CustomParameters" type="CustomParametersType" />
      <xsd:element name="PublishURI" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="PrintFrameURI" type="xsd:anyURI" />
      <xsd:element name="SessionID" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="UIType">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="UiOverride" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="CssOverride" type="xsd:string" />        
      <xsd:element name="SinglePageLayout" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:element name="EnableRasterRenderer" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:element name="Hide" type="HideType" />        
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="HideType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Widget" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xsd:element name="Tool" type="xsd:string"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="LicensesType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="License" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="FeaturesType">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="Search" type="SearchType" />
      <xsd:element name="Thumbnails" type="ThumbnailsType" />
      <xsd:element name="Markups" type="MarkupsType" />
      <xsd:element name="Print" type="PrintType" />
      <xsd:element name="Publish" type="PublishType" />
      <xsd:element name="ViewMode" type="ViewModeType" />
      <xsd:element name="TextSelect" type="TextSelectType" />
      <xsd:element name="Download" type="DownloadType" />
      <xsd:element name="ExportBanners" type="ExportBannersType" />
      <xsd:element name="Redactions" type="RedactionsType" />
      <xsd:element name="ESignature" type="ESignatureType" />
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="ExportBannersType">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="PersistSettingsOnNewBanner" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:element name="PresetsURL" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="Watermark" type="WatermarkType" />
      <xsd:element name="TopLeft" type="BannerType" />
      <xsd:element name="TopCenter" type="BannerType" />
      <xsd:element name="TopRight" type="BannerType" />
      <xsd:element name="BottomLeft" type="BannerType" />
      <xsd:element name="BottomCenter" type="BannerType" />
      <xsd:element name="BottomRight" type="BannerType" />
      <xsd:element name="LeftTop" type="BannerType" />
      <xsd:element name="LeftCenter" type="BannerType" />
      <xsd:element name="LeftBottom" type="BannerType" />
      <xsd:element name="RightTop" type="BannerType" />
      <xsd:element name="RightCenter" type="BannerType" />
      <xsd:element name="RightBottom" type="BannerType" />
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="BannerType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Text" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="Color" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="Editable" type="xsd:boolean" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="WatermarkType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="BannerType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="Opacity" type="xsd:decimal" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="DownloadType">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="DocumentURI" type="xsd:anyURI" />
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="AnyType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:any minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="TextSelectType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Enabled" type="xsd:boolean" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="ViewModeType">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="InitialZoom" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="MarkupEdit" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="RotateAll" type="xsd:int" />
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="PublishType">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="TIFFTimeoutMinutes" type="xsd:int" />
      <xsd:element name="PDFTimeoutMinutes" type="xsd:int" />
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="PrintType">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="TimeoutMinutes" type="xsd:int" />
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="CustomParametersType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Param" type="ParamType" minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="ParamType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="Value" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="SaveParamTypes">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="SaveParams" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="MarkupsType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="SaveParameters" type="SaveParamTypes" />
      <xsd:element name="ChangemarkConfigURI" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="EnableMarkupOverwrite" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:element name="AlwaysOverrideSave" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:element name="EnableAutosave" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:element name="AutosaveMinutes" type="xsd:int" />
      <xsd:element name="StampPreviewSize" type="xsd:int" />
      <xsd:element name="ImagePreviewSize" type="xsd:int" />
      <xsd:element name="Markup" type="MarkupType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xsd:element name="MarkupListURI" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="MarkupEditListURI" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xsd:element name="MarkupReviewListURI" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="MarkupSaveURI" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="MarkupDeleteURI" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="MarkupType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="OpenForEdit" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="URI" type="xsd:anyURI" />
      <xsd:element name="Author" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Date" type="xsd:decimal"/>
      <xsd:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="ThumbnailsType">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="InitialWidth" type="xsd:int" />
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="SearchType">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="MatchCase" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:element name="WholeWord" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:element name="RegEx" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:element name="EnableTermHits" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:element name="DefaultTermHits" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:element name="InitialSearch" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="DocumentsType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Document" type="DocumentType" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="DocumentType">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="ScreenBanner" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="ScreenWatermark" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="ESignatureType">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="AcknowledgeText" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="EnableRasterEdit" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:element name="Images" type="ImagesType" />
      <xsd:element name="EnableRasterSaves" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:element name="ESigRasterSaveURL" type="xsd:anyURI" />
      <xsd:element name="EnableAutoTemplateCreation" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xsd:element name="AutoTemplateInformation" type="AutoTemplateInformationType" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="AutoTemplateInformationType">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="TotalSigners" type="xsd:int" />
      <xsd:element name="CurrentSigner" type="xsd:int" />
      <xsd:element name="InitialsLocation" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="ImagesType">
    <xsd:all minOccurs="0">
      <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="Sign" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="Seal" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="Date" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="Initial" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="RedactionsType">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name="RedactionReasonsURI" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="RedactionPatternsURI" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

The exact exception I am getting is:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1682; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'MarkupListURI'. One of '{MarkupDeleteURI}' is expected.

Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: The following code was added to the xml as suggested:

```
<Markup>
  <OpenForEdit>true</OpenForEdit>
  <URI>http://www.google.com/URI</URI>
  <Author>Kenneth</Author>
  <Title>Owner</Title>
  <Date>9.55</Date>
</Markup>
```

Same error is displayed when attempting to validate the XML against the XSD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is your Markups definition:

```
<xsd:complexType name="MarkupsType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="SaveParameters" type="SaveParamTypes" />
      <xsd:element name="ChangemarkConfigURI" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="EnableMarkupOverwrite" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:element name="AlwaysOverrideSave" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:element name="EnableAutosave" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <xsd:element name="AutosaveMinutes" type="xsd:int" />
      <xsd:element name="StampPreviewSize" type="xsd:int" />
      <xsd:element name="ImagePreviewSize" type="xsd:int" />
      <xsd:element name="Markup" type="MarkupType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xsd:element name="MarkupListURI" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="MarkupEditListURI" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xsd:element name="MarkupReviewListURI" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="MarkupSaveURI" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="MarkupDeleteURI" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

and this is your submited XML:

```
<Markups>
        <SaveParameters>
          <SaveParams/>
        </SaveParameters>
        <ChangemarkConfigURI>http://www.google.com/CHANGEMARK_CONFIG_URI</ChangemarkConfigURI>
        <EnableMarkupOverwrite>true</EnableMarkupOverwrite>
        <AlwaysOverrideSave>true</AlwaysOverrideSave>
        <EnableAutosave>true</EnableAutosave>
        <AutosaveMinutes>7</AutosaveMinutes>
        <StampPreviewSize>8</StampPreviewSize>
        <ImagePreviewSize>0</ImagePreviewSize>
        <MarkupEditListURI>http://www.google.com/MARKUP_EDIT_LIST_URI</MarkupEditListURI>
        <MarkupReviewListURI>http://www.google.com/MARKUP_REVIEW_LIST_URI</MarkupReviewListURI>
        <MarkupSaveURI>http://www.google.com/MARKUP_SAVE_URI</MarkupSaveURI>
        <MarkupListURI>http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL/markups/9cb5b8fe-62d8-4d52-ba32-58f1d1cc5909?bravaserverurl=http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL</MarkupListURI>
        <MarkupDeleteURI>http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL/markups/delete/9cb5b8fe-62d8-4d52-ba32-58f1d1cc5909?clientid=1234&amp;bravaserverurl=http://www.google.com/BRAVA_SERVER_URL</MarkupDeleteURI>
      </Markups>
```

I don't see `Markup` element in your XML. Please check it!

**UPDATE:** Your definition use `sequence` not `all`. [xs:sequence specifies that the child elements must appear in a sequence.](http://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/ug-editor/topics/xml-schema-diagram-compositors-properties.html) Please try `all` or add elements in sequence.

Comment: With "Markup" having minOccurs as 0 would it be a required element?

Comment: Changing the type in the xsd from `xsd:sequence` to `xsd:all` may fixes that problem, however, with the element type `Markup` being listed with `maxOccurence="unbound"` this causes a separate validation failure.  I am checking to see if the element needs to have the `maxOccurence="unbound"` attribute with it or not, if not updating to `xsd:all` would solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Short version:**

Read the error message again, carefully. Think about why the validator issued that particular message, where it might have been in reading the document, and where the corresponding place might be in the schema.
Look at those two places and see if you think the document shown is valid against the schema shown.

**Long version:**

Your `Markups` element is declared as having type `MarkupsType`.  That type expects a long list of element types, from `SaveParameters` down through `MarkupDeleteURI`.  The `Markups` element in the instance you show has a lot of elements, most of which match the type declaration.  But the instance includes an element named `MarkupListURI`, right before the element named `MarkupDeleteURI`.  The type declaration doesn't include any reference to, or local declaration of, any such element.  So the `MarkupListURI` element cannot validly occur where it does, given the schema you're showing. (This is what the error message is trying to tell you.  It found a MarkupListURI element when it was expecting a MarkupDeleteURI.)

Either the document is wrong and needs to be fixed by deleting the `MarkupListURI` element, or the schema is wrong and needs to be fixed by repairing the content model of MarkupsType to say what it is intended to say.

Comment: I think error message trying tell for us It's get another element which is excepted -> `One of '{MarkupDeleteURI}' is expected`.

Comment: Looking at multiple responses from the API, it looks like the API is returning the `MarkupListURI` in a different order depending on the parameters that are passed.  I was missing this earlier, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turns out that value of the element was string containing line break.